# Rowwise matrix multiplication, what is the name of this?

Tags: matrices, terminology

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\operatorname{SomeOperation}(A)=\begin{pmatrix}1*2*3 \\ 1*1*1\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}6 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$. What is the operation $\operatorname{SomeOperation}$?

Comment: It is whatever you want to call it. Too unnatural to have a standard name.

Comment: I'd call it muckification.

Answer (score 1):

If $A > 0$, you can express this using elementwise functions
$$
  exp(log(A)\cdot u)
$$
Where $u$ is a vector of ones.

Comment: Can you give your definition of the logarithm for a matrix?

Comment: @hhh: It's on Wikipedia. (And requires $A$ be square, which is inherent in the positive-definiteness condition Glynne writes, $A>0$.)